# How to fix 'The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST' error

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to post a form and I am getting an error

Here is my view **create.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <form action="/p" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            @csrf

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-8 offset-2">

                    <div class="row">
                        <h1>Add New Post</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="caption" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Post Caption</label>

                        <input id="caption"
                               type="text"
                               class="form-control{{ $errors->has('caption') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                               name="caption"
                               value="{{ old('caption') }}"
                               autocomplete="caption" autofocus>

                        @if ($errors->has('caption'))
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('caption') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <label for="image" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Post Image</label>

                        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="image" name="image">

                        @if ($errors->has('image'))
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('image') }}</strong>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    <div class="row pt-4">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">Add New Post</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
@endsection
```

my routes **web.php**

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
j|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/p/create', 'PostsController@create');
Route::post('/p', 'PostsController@store');

Route::get('/profile/{user}', 'ProfilesController@index')->name('profile.show');
```

and my controller **Posts.Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function create(){
        return view('posts.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request){
        $data = $request->validate([
            'caption' => 'required',
            'image' => ['required', 'image'],
        ]);

        Post::create($data);

        dd($request->all());
    }
}
```

Here is the error I am getting:

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \
>   MethodNotAllowedHttpException The GET method is not supported for this
>   route. Supported methods: POST.

Comment: What steps or actions are you taking that lead you to that error?

Comment: add @method('POST') after @csrf in form . hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Give you route a name and then use it

**this**

```
Route::post('/p', 'PostsController@store');
```

**to**

```
Route::post('/p', 'PostsController@store')->name('pstore');
```

**add your route like this**

```
<form action="{{ route('pstore') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

**Could you try to change this**

```html
<form action="/p" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

**into this**

```html
<form action="{{ url('/p')} }" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

**or this**

```html
<form action="{{ route('PostsController@store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Give the name to your Route. and than use that name to form action.
see below code:

**Route:** 2 way you can write Route.

```
Route::post('/p', 'PostsController@store')->name('post_store');
```

*OR*

```
Route::post('/p',['as' => 'post_store', 'uses' => 'PostsController@store']);
```

**create.blade.php:**

```
<form action="{{ route('post_store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```